# stack 10 modis ndvi geotiffs and scale them by 0.0001

Tags: gdal, remote-sensing, scale, modis, stack

I have 10 geotiffs Modis ndvi named 2005.tif ... 2014.tif 
I want to stack them all and create timeseries. i know how to do that, but the stacked images still need scaling by 0.0001. how can i bulk scale them using gdal -scale function before stacking them?

---

Tried the first line on OSGeo, but when openning the new tifs all I can see is 0s and 1s. any idea?

Answer (score 5):

In Windows (run OSGeo4W shell):

Scaling:

```
for %i in (*.tif) DO gdal_translate -scale -2000 10000 -0.2 1 %i outputs\%i
```

You might find recalculating instead better:

```
for %i in (*.tif) DO gdal_calc.bat -A %i --outfile=outputs\%i --calc="A*0.0001" --NoDataValue=0
```

In Ubuntu looping through files is slightly different:

```
for i in *.tif; do
    gdal_calc -A $i ...
done
```

Comment: Tried the -scale -2000 10000 -0.2 1 but it gave me a tif with only 0 and 1 as output, nothing in between.

Comment: try setting -ot Float32